# PageView are not updating while traversing on the website - GTM & GA

Tags: html, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, adblock

Created a new GA Id and attached it in GTA.
Added the two JS code in the HTML page of my website.
Created a tag in GTM for GA with pageview for all pages of my website. (as shown below)[image]

Now, Whenever, I opened any web URL of my website, it is coming up in the real-time overview in GA.
But when I traverse on my website using links, buttons, CTA that is not reflecting in the real-time overview at all. But when I opened those links directly in the browser, it will come up in GA.
I am really confused about this. Please help. I am really new to GA & GTA.

Comment: Is it a onepage site?

Comment: Actually, Yes. I have to create custom page views for that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: Actually yes...